# Regular Expression: how can I impose a perfect string matching?

Tags: regex

Currently I am using this one ( **edit: I missed to explain that I use this one for excluding exactly these words  :p**  ):

```
   String REGEXP = "^[^(REG_)?].*";
```

but matches (exluding) also ERG, EGR, GRE, etc... above

P.S. 
I removed super because it is another keyword that I must filter, figure an array list composed with more of the following three words to be used as model:

REG_info1, info2, SUPER_info3, etc...

I need three filter matching one model at time, my question focus only on the second filter parsing keywords based on model "info2".

Comment: Do you want it to start with REG_ or do you want it to NOT start with REG_?

Comment: I need all words not starting with "REG_" or "SUPER_", with a perfect string match on this prefix, tnx :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just type it literally:

```
REG
```

This will only match `REG`.

So:

```
String REGEXP = "^(REG_|SUPER_)?.*";
```

---

**Edit**   After you clarified that you want to match every word that does *not* begin with `REG_` or `SUPER_`, you could try this:

```
\b(?!REG_|SUPER_)\w+
```

The `\b` is a word boundary and the expression `(?!`*`expr`*`)` is a look-ahead assertion.

Comment: Thank you, I remembered something about !, but I was not able to use it because initially I did use it in the wrong manner, now I learned that it is part of "look ahead" assertion :-)

Comment: Great Gumbo! now all wotks perfectly

Answer (score 2):

As everyone have already replied, if you want to match a line starting with REG, you use the regexp "^REG", if you want to match any line that starts REG or SUPER, you use "^(REG|SUPER)" and regular expression negation is, in general, a tricky problem.

To match all lines NOT starting with 'REG' you need to match "^[^R]|R[^E]|RE[^G]" and a regular expression to match all lines not starting with REG or SUPER can be constructed in a similar fashion (start by grouping the "not REG" in parentheses, then construct the "not SUPER" patterns as "[^S]|S[^U]|[SU[^P]...", group this and use alternation for both groups).

Comment: You have to group the character description: `^([^R]|R[^E]|RE[^G])`. Otherwise the anchor `^` is only refered to the `[^R]`.

Comment: You hit the my scope, others have misunderstood my first sentence saying I need a perfect matching, but I need an exact match during an excluding match

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
\mREG\M

// \mREG\M
// 
// Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks
// 
// Assert position at the beginning of a word «\m»
// Match the characters “REG” literally «REG»
// Assert position at the end of a word «\M»
```

Answer (score 0):

The [] indicate character classes. This is not what you want. You can just use "REG" to match REG. (You can use REG|SUPER for REG or SUPER)

Answer (score 0):

```
REGEXP = "^(REG_|SUPER_)"
```

would match anything that haves REG_ or SUPER_ at the beginning of a string. You don't need more after the group "(..|..)"